# Re-sizing does not introduce scroll bar on time

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I don't understand why my vertical scrollbar does not show until I resize the container to be smaller than its height minus horz scrollbar height....

What am I doing wrong or is this a bug?

Thanks

[image: I would expect to see a vertical scrollbar now!]

[image: Now the vertical scroll is introduced....!!]

with this code:

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var settings = {
                showArrows: false
            };

            $('.myContainer').jScrollPane(settings);

            var api = $('.myContainer').data('jsp');

            var throttleTimeout;
            $(window).bind(
                'resize',
                function () {
                    if ($.browser.msie) {
                        // IE fires multiple resize events while you are dragging the browser window which
                        // causes it to crash if you try to update the scrollpane on every one. So we need
                        // to throttle it to fire a maximum of once every 50 milliseconds...
                        if (!throttleTimeout) {
                            throttleTimeout = setTimeout(
                                function () {
                                    api.reinitialise();
                                    throttleTimeout = null;
                                },
                                50
                            );
                        }
                    } else {
                        api.reinitialise();
                    }
                }
            );

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: its better if you create a fiddle

Comment: will do in a moment -